# Rounding time to aggregate entries close in time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to sum together `content_len` that are entered into the database a few seconds apart (colour coded). The table currently breaks into a new row once the character count hits 999, and inserts each overflow a few seconds apart. Due to errors, the overflow can be timestamped earlier than the previous body.

[image]

My current attempt is to round the timestamp to unix seconds, but issues occur when the rounding (`unix_ceil`) does not produce the same number for content that are to be grouped together. How can I ensure that entries that are within ~20 seconds of each other are summed together? Usually there is a separation of at least a few minutes between distinct records that are not to be grouped together (e.g. 999+37 at ~0950am and then 136 at ~0959am for `source` = 1).

```sql
SELECT source
,entry_dt 
,SUM(content_len) AS full_length
FROM (
    SELECT source
    ,entry_dt
    ,entry_time
    ,(TO_DATE(CONCAT(entry_dt, entry_time), 'yyyymmddHH24MISS') - TO_DATE('2020-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) * 86400 AS unix_from_2020
    ,CEIL(86400 * (TO_DATE(CONCAT(entry_dt, entry_time), 'yyyymmddHH24MISS') - TO_DATE('2020-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) / 20) * 20 AS unix_ceil -- round to 20 seconds
    ,content_len
    FROM schema.text_length_records
) s
GROUP BY source, entry_dt, unix_ceil
```

Comment: If you have one entry at time `0` then a second at time `19` and a third at time `25` then are they all in the same group (since the second is within 20 seconds of the first and the third is within 20 seconds of the second) or are there two groups (since the third is not within 20 seconds of the first)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not store dates and times separately and do not store them in non-`DATE` data types. In Oracle a `DATE` is a binary data type consisting of 7 bytes which contain the components century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second and it **ALWAYS** has those components and is **NEVER** stored in any particular format.

You can then use a single `DATE` column to store both date and time and do it more efficiently and with better error checking than if you store the values separately as strings or numbers.

---

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to do row-by-row processing.

If you want each row to be within 20 seconds of the previous row then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT source,
         TO_DATE(entry_dt || LPAD(entry_time, '0', 6), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') AS entry_dt,
         content_len
  FROM   text_length_records
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY source
  ORDER     BY entry_dt
  MEASURES
    FIRST(entry_dt)  AS start_entry_dt,
    LAST(entry_dt)   AS end_entry_dt,
    SUM(content_len) AS content_len
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  PATTERN (within_20* last_time)
  DEFINE
    within_20 AS entry_dt + INTERVAL '20' SECOND >= NEXT(entry_dt)
)
```

If you want each row to be within 20 seconds of the first row of the group then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT source,
         TO_DATE(entry_dt || LPAD(entry_time, 6, '0'), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') AS entry_dt,
         content_len
  FROM   text_length_records
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY source
  ORDER     BY entry_dt
  MEASURES
    FIRST(entry_dt)  AS start_entry_dt,
    LAST(entry_dt)   AS end_entry_dt,
    SUM(content_len) AS content_len
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  PATTERN (within_20*)
  DEFINE
    within_20 AS entry_dt <= FIRST(entry_dt) + INTERVAL '20' SECOND
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE text_length_records (source, entry_dt, entry_time, content_len) AS
SELECT 1, 20210910, 95059,  37 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 20210910, 95102, 999 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 20210910, 95959, 139 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 20210910, 83320, 999 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 20210910, 83322, 999 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 20210910, 83324, 456 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | SOURCE | START_ENTRY_DT | END_ENTRY_DT | CONTENT_LEN |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2021-09-10 09:50:59 | 2021-09-10 09:51:02 | 1036 |
> | 1 | 2021-09-10 09:59:59 | 2021-09-10 09:59:59 | 139 |
> | 2 | 2021-09-10 08:33:20 | 2021-09-10 08:33:24 | 2454 |

*Note: Although the queries produce the same output for your sample data, they will produce slightly different outputs if you did have any sample data where the 3<sup>th</sup> row was not within 20 seconds of the 1<sup>st</sup> row of the group but was within 20 seconds of the 2<sup>nd</sup> row of the group.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f821e15e7f821973b013dac398ff2ffa)*

Comment: Thanks for this! I was unaware of this function. Could you explain the * and what last_time is referencing/doing? I realised that it works no matter what it is renamed as.

Comment: @fluent The `PATTERN` clause sets the pattern for how rows are matched and is mostly similar to regular expression pattern matching. In this case, the pattern `within_20` can be matched zero-or-more (as denoted by the `*`) times and then the `last_time` pattern will be matched exactly once. The `within_20` pattern is defined in the `DEFINE` clause but the `last_time` is not and, in that case, would match any row. Yes, you can rename it to anything or you could add it to the `DEFINE` clause as anything that is always true such as `DEFINE last_time AS 1 = 1, within_20 AS ...`.